# Transfer account from one server to another server using cPanel

Tags: migration, backup, cpanel, transfer

I am not a server person and I am having issues with this particular transfer. I have transferred accounts in the past with success.

With this particular transfer, I always come across this error:

```
ERROR: tar of split archive ran out of space
```

I increased the quota on the old server for this account but that did not correct the issue. Additionally, one of the disks on the old server is 69% full. How would I go about freeing up some memory?

I'd like to avoid having to do this manually as the account I am trying to transfer is very large.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to transfer this account differently.  This procedure should work for you, but will require some more sysadmin expertise.  As a summary, you're going to make a cPanel backup minus the home directory (generally the largest folder), restore that backup, and then rsync the home directory over to the server.

1. On the old server run: `/scripts/pkgacct --skiphomedir <username here>`
2. Restore the cPanel backup on the new server.
3. On the old server, run the following command: `rsync -zaHlv -e ssh /home/<username here>/* <username here>@<new server here>:/home/<username here>/`

This will take time, but will get the entire home directory moved over.